# return arraylist from a file

Tags: java, file, arraylist

Method takes name of a file,I need to return an `ArrayList<<ArrayList<String>>` where each line is converted to `ArrayList<String>` with each String being a word from that line.

The txt file I have is this

```
Twinkle twinkle little star
How I wonder what you are
Up above the world so high
Like a diamond in the sky
```

so it should return an arraylist of size 4 whose elements is an arraylist of strings of size 4, and the second element is an arraylist of strings of size 6 and so on

however I'm not sure how to turn lines into single string, this is what I have so far

```
public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> file (String fname){
  ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> w1 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
  ArrayList<String> w2 = new ArrayList<String>();
  try{ 
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new FileReader(fname));
    String line= "";    

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
        w2.add(line);
        w1.add(w2);
    }

  }catch(IOException e){
      System.out.println("An error occured");
  } 
  return w1;
}
```

Comment: For each line you read, you need to 1) split it into words 2) add those words to a *new* `ArrayList<String>`, then 3) add that `ArrayList<String>` to the larger `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`

Answer (score 2):

```
public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> file (String fname){
      ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> w1 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
      ArrayList<String> w2 = new ArrayList<String>();
      try{ 
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new FileReader(fname));
        String line= "";    

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
            //take each line and split them around a space
            String[] individualWords = line.split("\\s+");
            //now convert the string[] to an arraylist
            w2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(individualWords));
            //now add it to your main arraylist of arraylist strings
            w1.add(w2);
        }

      }catch(IOException e){
          System.out.println("An error occured");
      } 
      return w1;
    }
```

Comment: `line.split( "\\s+" );` would probably be better as it would split the line on any space characters.

Comment: that sounds like a mighty fine idea ill make the change, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just

```
public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> file (String fname){
    return Files.lines(Paths.get(fname))
                .map(line -> line.split("\\s+"))
                .map(words -> Arrays.stream(words).collect(Collectors.toList()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```